# See specific data of array

Tags: php, arrays

How could you see the first note of 'person1', the second note of 'person2' and the third note of 'person3'?

I've been trying it this way but it does not work for me.
$ student ['notes'] [0] [1])

```
$person1 = [
   'name' => 'person1',
   'notes' => [1,2,3]
];

$person2 = [
   'name' => 'person2',
   'notes' => [4,5,6]
];

$person3 = [
   'name' => 'person3',
   'notes' => [7,8,9]
];

$data=[$person1,$person2,$person3];


foreach ($data as $student) {

   echo "<br>";
   echo $student['name']." " . "= ";
   echo implode (', ', $student['notes']);
   echo "<br>";
}


//Result
//person1 = 1, 2, 3
//person2 = 4, 5, 6
//person3 = 7, 8, 9


//Expected
//person1 = 1 (see the first 'note' data)
//person2 = 5 (see the second data of 'notes')
//person3 = 9 (see the third data of 'notes')


// It does not work with this form but can it be something like that?
// $student['notes'][0][1])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm interpreting your question correctly, you are asking how to target particular elements of a multidimensional array:

```
<?php
$data =
[
    [
        'name' => 'person1',
        'notes' => [1,2,3]
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'person2',
        'notes' => [4,5,6]
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'person3',
        'notes' => [7,8,9]
    ]
];

echo $data[0]['notes'][0], "\n"; // First note of first person
echo $data[1]['notes'][1], "\n"; // Second note of second person
echo $data[2]['notes'][2], "\n"; // Third note of third person
```

Output:

```
1
5
9
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you can alter your loop to include the `index` and use the pattern you described to target the correct note based on your index position:

```
foreach ($data as $index => $student) {

   echo "<br>";
   echo $student['name']." " . "= ";
   echo $student['notes'][$index];
   echo "<br>";
}
```

You have to make sure you will always have as many notes as the index you accessing thought

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$person1 = [
    'name' => 'person1',
    'notes' => [1,2,3]
];

$person2 = [
    'name' => 'person2',
    'notes' => [4,5,6]
];

$person3 = [
    'name' => 'person3',
    'notes' => [7,8,9]
];

$data=[$person1,$person2,$person3];
echo '<pre>';
$counter = 0;
foreach ($data as $student) {

    echo $student['name']." " . "= " .$student['notes'][$counter];
    $counter++;
    echo '<br>';
}
```

And the output is:

```
person1 = 1
person2 = 5
person3 = 9
```

The way to solve this is simple use a counter. So for every loop you make you increase the counter by 1 and you point to that array field using your counter as an array key.